# How to derive the dimension of conformal Killing vector fields on the Riemann sphere? Is it metric independent?

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, vector-fields

**Context**

In all string textbooks and lecture notes, they derive the CKV on the sphere by considering the flat plane first, i.e. $(\mathbb{C},\delta_{\mu\nu})$. Then, write it in complex variables
$$z = x^1 + ix^2  $$
Consequently, the metric is then
$$ds^2 = dzd\bar{z}$$
As a result, the conformal transformations are generated by holomorphic function, i.e.
$$z' = f(z)$$
whose generators are $l_n = -z^{n+1}\partial_{z}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Requiring the generators are well behaved on entire complex plane leaves us only $l_n$ for $n = \pm 1,0 $.

Finally, these 3 globally well defined generators ($l_{\pm 1 , 0}$) are the CKV on Riemann sphere. Thus,
$$dim CKV = 3$$

**Question**

They derive the CKV on a specific metric instead of general one, i.e. the flat metric $\delta_{\mu\nu}$ at the beginning. However, we also know that CKV is defined through the equation :
$$\nabla_{\mu}X_{\nu} + \nabla_{\nu}X_{\mu} = \Omega g_{\mu\nu}$$
which explicitly depends on the metric. As a result, it seems to me that the dimension of the CKV is also dependent on the metric. But why all the books and lecture notes just overlook it?